# Tao, Analysis II, Theorem 6.3.8, mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

In page 141 Tao wrote:

From the mean value theorem in the $x_1$ variable, we see that
$$
f_i(x_0 + v_1 e_1) - f_i(x_0) = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_1}(x_0 + t_i e_1) v_1
$$
for some $t_i$ between $0$ and $v_1$.

But I can't see how one can proof that the function $g : [0, v] \to \mathbf{R}$, defined as follow, is differentiable on $(0, v)$:
$$
g(t) = f_i(x_0 + t e_1)
$$

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he assumes that all the partial derivatives of $f$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ exist as one of the hypotheses of the theorem and recall (see also page 139 in the book) that if $f$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then so will $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$. By writing $f$ in components, $f=(f_1,\dots, f_m)$ we have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_0)=(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(x_0), \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}(x_0),\dots, \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1}(x_0))$.

Comment: So how exactly can we write it in the form of limit?

Comment: @ProFatXuanAll which object are you referring to?

Comment: The derivative of function $g$ defined as above.

Comment: @ProFatXuanAll $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f_i(x_0+te_i)-f_i(x_0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t}$

Comment: Yes this is the part gave me the confusion. The equation you showed only tells me $g$ is differentiable at $0$, not on the interval $(0, v)$

Comment: @ProFatXuanAll notice that for $x\in (0,v)$ you are inside the ball $B(x_0,\delta)\subset F$ and by hypothesis all the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ exist on $F$ so that is why $g=f_i$ is differentiable on $(0,v)$